# VSTS build summary tab with visible condition or Task dependency

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines-build-task

I try to add new custom tab to summary page for build result, but which will be added only for builds with my custom build Task. For example, Task "publish artifacts", only if this task was added, the tab "artifacts" added in summary page. I want the same behavior for my task and tab.

For now, I've just added in vss-extension.json, in "contributions"

```
{
  "id": "build-info-tab",
  "type": "ms.vss-build-web.build-results-tab",
  "description": "A tab contributing to build results view",
  "targets": [
    "ms.vss-build-web.build-results-view"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "name": "My Build info",
    "uri": "infoTab.html",

  }
}
```

But this tab permanently displayed for any builds and that is my problem.

Actually I have the same issue with summary section also.

Comment: If you add the code in vss-extension.json, then the tab should be permanently displayed for any builds. This is the correct phenomenon. Adding some extension such as https://www.jfrog.com/blog/empowering-vststfs-with-jfrog-artifactory/ , then it will generate the custom tab for all build definition's build result. Even with those ones didn't use the task and the old records built before the extension installed.

Comment: But how to avoid this behaviour? How to add tab only if certain Task was added to build execution ?

Comment: Also looking for a way to hide the jfrog Artificatory tab as we have no usage for it, even for the very few builds that actually use Artifactory.